# R: read lines from .txt to int vectors

Tags: r, vector

I have file.txt containing long lines (of different length) of integers separates by whitespaces. Each line represents some array. I need to read them into R-vectors, get their medians, and collect these medians again in some R-vector, then plot it and return the minimum.

I`m having trouble with reading ints from line to vector, or should I use another structure here? 
Should the number of lines be specified, or can I use some loop until eof?

Can anyone give me some example how to do that??
Thanks a lot.

Comment: please show the example of a data file you are trying to read

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rXaEXAtv

Answer (score 2):

`read.table()` works nicely and is the quickest way, if the rows contain the same number of elements. If not, this is probably the most simple approach:

```
a<-paste(readLines("asdf.txt"),collapse=" ") #get data, put it into one big character string
b<-strsplit(a,split=" ") #seperate integers by whitespaces
b<-as.integer(b[[1]]) #define them as integers
str(b)
# int [1:522] -3 -5 -2 3 6 3 -1 -2 -2 -2 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
file<-read.table(file.choose(),dec=".",sep=" ",header=TRUE);
apply(file,1,median)
```

file.choose() open file manager to let you choose the file 
(It could give some issues on macyntosh)
dec stands for decimal symbol(usually . or ,)
sep stands for separtor ("," for csv, space for your case)

apply is a function that let you apply  the same formula to rows and columns 
You have to specify 1 for rows, 2 for columns

header if you have the header or not

your case

```
file<-read.table('https://pastebin.com/raw/rXaEXAtv')
medians<-apply(file,1,median)
plot(medians)
min(medians)
```

Like Axeman points out this will work only in case each rows has the same 
number of columns, that is you can organize the rows in a dataframe

**EDIT 
Case Unequal Number Of Columns**

```
file<-file('https://pastebin.com/raw/rXaEXAtv',open="rt") #open connection with the file
nFields <- count.fields(file) #find number of field for row
n=length(nFields) #find number of rows
close(file) #close connection we need to point to the start of the file
#(Windows seek is broken)

file<-file('https://pastebin.com/raw/rXaEXAtv',open="rt") #reopen connection, the pointer now is at first row again
data<-list() #init list data structure
scan(file,what=1,nlines=1,sep=" ") #skip first blank row

for(i in 1:(n) ){
data[[i]]=scan(file,what=1,nlines=1,sep=" ") # read line one each time
}
close(file) 


medians<-unlist(lapply(data,median))
plot(medians)
min(medians)
```

Comment: But just `read.table('https://pastebin.com/raw/rXaEXAtv')` works fine? There aren't even decimal separators in the file.

Comment: yes, because sep=" " and dec="." are default arguments, but I thought was useful for a newbie at least understand main arguments, just in case he has a different file structure

Comment: Note that this will only work if the each line has the same number of elements (which is the case here, but the question seems to leave this open).

Comment: what if lines contain different number of elements?
The file can be modified, is there any better way to store this arrays in file.txt to make input more suitable?

Answer (score 0):

Read all lines (Make sure you put an empty line at the end)

```
allLines <- readLines(con = 'file.txt', n = -1)
```

Tokenize each line on empty space

```
tokenize <- strsplit(allLines,split = ' ')
```

If you want the result as matrix:

```
# Matrix
as_matrix <- sapply(tokenize, FUN = function(x) {as.integer(unlist(x))} )
```

If you want the result as list of lists:

```
# as list of list
a <- lapply(tokenize, FUN = function(x) {as.integer(unlist(x))} )
```